# How to read numerical data from CSV in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I'm new to PyTorch; trying to implement a model I developed in TF and compare the results. The model is an Autoencoder model. The input data is a csv file including n samples each with m features (a n*m numerical matrix in a csv file). The targets (the labels) are in another csv file with the same format as the input file. I've been looking online but couldn't find a good documentation for reading non-image data from csv file with multiple labels. Any idea how can I read my data and iterate over it during training?

Thank you

Comment: why don't you use `pandas` to load the dataset and then pytorch-related classes to frame it inside the tensors?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm looking for something similar to tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset in TF. So I can shuffle the data and stream the data without needing to manually create batches of data.

Answer (score 3):

Might you be looking for something like [TabularDataset](https://pytorch.org/text/data.html#tabulardataset)?

> class
>   torchtext.data.TabularDataset(path, format, fields, skip_header=False, csv_reader_params={}, **kwargs)
>
> Defines a Dataset of columns stored in CSV, TSV, or JSON format.

It will take a path to a CSV file and build a dataset from it. You also need to specify the names of the columns which will then become the data fields.

In general, all of implementations of torch.Dataset for specific types of data are located outside of pytorch in the torchvision, torchtext, and torchaudio libraries.